# New chrome version 54.0.2840.87 break the file auto download in selenium chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the latest selenium  chromedriver_win32_2.25 driver. Today after I updated the my Chrome to 54.0.2840.87. I can not do the auto downloading. The Chrome will pop up and window "XXX.zip is malicious, and Chrome has blocked it" . I found out I can disable this alert by turning **off** the Chrome option "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites". This is the opposite way to allowing auto download before (Check the post [How to disable 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up))

The following code is not working:

```
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false");
        prefs.put("safebrowsing.malware.enabled", "false");
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false"); 
        prefs.put( "profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1 );
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDir);           
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Not sure what is the lastest parameters for the "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites"

Seems prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false"); not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  After a bit of research, I tried:

options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);

rather than my original:

options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*,*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1);

...and it worked just fine, now.  This is when I went to Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After I tried many times, it is always working whether "safebrowsing.enabled" is "false" or "ture". This is fixed automatically.

Comment: What language is in your answer, php?  Do you have a version in good old javascript?  I'm using Chrome. It gave me Yes/NO prompt (not desirable!) for downloading multiple files. All I need is setting multiple-automatic-downloads" to 1 (true) !!  Because I do not want to see the prompt asking it.