# Selenium: "This type of file can harm your computer"

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download an XML file from a website. When the file is downloaded, the browser shows a message: "This type of file can harm your computer".

However it works on other computers.
I tried:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");            
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing", "enabled");
```

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up/34174633#comment56125532_34174633

Comment: Yes, I did. It occurs in version 62 +.