# Zalenium: Disable the download popup in the chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, popup, save, zalenium

i am running an automation test via Chrome on Zalenium, in which we try download a pdf file. Unfortunately, when we try to download it, we see the download pop up window, which we cannot handle it due to framework limitations. How can we disable the popup on chrome in Zalenium?

I see a relative issue here:

https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/1115

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser preference, not really depeding on Zalenium, it is called `download.default_directory`. To avoid repeating myself, here is another SO entry solving it [How to disable or accept the Chrome pop up while downloading using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219359/how-to-disable-or-accept-the-chrome-pop-up-while-downloading-using-selenium)