# How to download XML files avoiding the popup This type of file may harm your computer through ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to download a daily xml file from a supplier. I managed to login and click the link Accept Download to start the downloading using chromedriver.

But I get the popup "This type of file may harm your computer". The MIME of the page is text/html, I am not sure if link is text/javascript

I tried all suggested solutions with options like

```
print('Starting..')
prefs = {
'download.default_directory': 'C:\\Users\MainDesk\Downloads',
'download.prompt_for_download': False,
'download.extensions_to_open': 'xml',
'safebrowsing.enabled': False
}

options = Options()

options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='C:\\chromedriver.exe')
```

How can I have my file automatically?

Additionaly I tried go in Settings of Chrome and turn off Ask to save file

I am running the script on Windows 7, with Python 3.7 and Visual Studio and the latest version of chromedriver

It is impossible to automate my download?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up  Looks like switch --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection

Comment: I checked it is not working :(

Comment: you tried the suggestions in that link?

Comment: Yes with all variations :) I could think of

Comment: If I do it manually never asks for permission to download it

Comment: Can you share the reference page link/url?

Comment: @Deban the link is under login unfortunately, I think is not downloading properly because the link is not ending with ..filename.xml but with ...asp

Comment: Fair enough, then how do you expect your question to be answered?

Comment: Initially Is my code syntax correct? , is it because of visual studio? Shall I use firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more information about *webpage* from where you are trying to *download* the **xml** file might have been helpful to debug the issue of the popup with text as **"This type of file may harm your computer** in a better way.

However here is a sample program to download **xml** file from [this webpage](http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  prefs = {
  'download.default_directory': 'C:/Utility/Downloads/',
  'download.prompt_for_download': False,
  'download.extensions_to_open': 'xml',
  'safebrowsing.enabled': True
  }
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
  options.add_argument("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='MntnRoad.xml']//following::span[1]//a[text()='Download']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: xml_download]

Comment: I finally used geckodriver and automatically the file is saved to Downloads

Comment: Is it working just because your code clicks the popup button (**WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='MntnRoad.xml']//following::span[1]//a[text()='Download']"))).click()**) or it accepted the properties?

Comment: @FelipeCaparelli The _properties_ and `element_to_be_clickable()` both are equally significant when dealing with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871)

Comment: @DebanjanB, I've downvoted the answer because it is not working for me (I am not using the last line - to select the button), but I believe that the other properties should work or it is just unnecessary, right?