# 'Options' object has no attribute 'set_preference' error using ChromeOptions in Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download pdf with clicking on Download button using selenium and python. But getting this above mentioned error while running Chrome and my full test developed for chrome browser.

```html
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-full-layout/div/div[2]/div/div/div/app-list/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button").click()
time.sleep(7)
options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 0)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/DFS")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/octet-stream,application/pdf")
driver = driver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.options)
```

Expected execute this code and download the pdf file

Comment: You expect the code to run even when you reference a non-existing attribute? Or you expect `options` to have an attribute `set_preference`? Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

[selenium.webdriver.chrome.options](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options) *Class* doesn't include the method `set_preference()`

[`set_preference(name, value)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options.set_preference) is from the [selenium.webdriver.firefox.options](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options.set_preference) *Class*.

So while working with *ChromeOptions* for *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome*, you need to use [**`add_argument(argument)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options.add_argument) method instead as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
options.add_argument("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to download XML files avoiding the popup This type of file may harm your computer through ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407388/how-to-download-xml-files-avoiding-the-popup-this-type-of-file-may-harm-your-com/55413305#55413305)

Comment: You might want to add the option `add_experimental_option` if I understand you can add prefs there...