# vsd file download issue

Tags: java, selenium, download

The following question and answer suggests various ways of suppressing the message "this type of file can harm your computer" but I am still having an issue with .vsd files ( microsoft visio )

[How to disable 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up)

I have already tried all the solutions provided in the above link.

```
Map<String, Object> prefsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefsMap.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefsMap.put("download.default_directory", fileDownloadPath);
prefsMap.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
prefsMap.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true"); 

//assign driver properties
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefsMap);
option.addArguments("--test-type");
option.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
option.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
option.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");


WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Please guide me if I am missing something so that I could download .vsd files without displaying the warning message.

As suggested I tried the solution at the following URL

[How to download XML files avoiding the popup This type of file may harm your computer through ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407388/how-to-download-xml-files-avoiding-the-popup-this-type-of-file-may-harm-your-com)

I have changed the code to download a vsd file from a public site

```
public class LocalDownloadTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    //Chrome driver and set download directory
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    String fileDownloadPath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads"; 
    //String linkText = "default";

    //Set properties to supress popups
            Map<String, Object> prefsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            prefsMap.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
            prefsMap.put("download.default_directory", fileDownloadPath);
            prefsMap.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            prefsMap.put("download.extensions_to_open", "vsd");
            prefsMap.put("download.extensions_to_open", "vsdx");
            prefsMap.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
            prefsMap.put("plugins.always_open_vsd_externally", true);
            prefsMap.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true"); 

            //assign driver properties
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefsMap);
            option.addArguments("--test-type");
            option.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            option.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
            option.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");


            WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver(option);


    //download file from portal
    driver.get("https://www.stakeholdermap.com/business-analysis/raise-purchase-order-flow-chart.html");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.vsd')]")).click();

    }


}
```

I am still getting the warning message. It has taken a lot of my time and effort for hit and trial but the problem hasn't been solved yet. Please advise some workaround for this.

Comment: @DebanjanB this is not a duplicate entry. I have tried solutions posted on the link that you suggested and still having issues

Comment: Can you update the question with some demo links to download `vsd` files?

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added the working code to download a vsd file from some public site. I can still see the keep, discard dialogue while trying to download the file.

Comment: @DebanjanB can you please have a look at the working example in the question to download .vsd file.