# Web Scraping XML file that's Downloaded After Submitting Form (Python)

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

How do you scrape an xml file that automatically downloads to your computer after submitting a form? I haven't seen any examples that contain a file that is from submitted data. I haven't been able to find it in the python documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html . Any suggestions, or links would be very much appreciated.

```py
   from selenium import webdriver
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
   from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
   from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
   
   url = 'https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/claims.asp'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
   
   driver.implicitly_wait(10)
   driver.get(url)
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="level"][value="state"]').click()
   Select(driver.find_element_by_name('strtdate')).select_by_value('2020')
   Select(driver.find_element_by_name('enddate')).select_by_value('2022')
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="filetype"][value="xml"]').click()
   select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('states'))

   # Iterate through and select all states
   for opt in select.options:
       opt.click()
   input('Press ENTER to submit the form')
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="submit"][value="Submit"]').click()
```

Comment: *web scrape an xml file*? Do you mean parse it for content? Why not use the etree library that you linked?

Comment: Yes, I mean parse it. I found something that put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post on stackoverflow seems to be in the direction of what I'm looking for; [How to download XML files avoiding the popup This type of file may harm your computer through ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407388/how-to-download-xml-files-avoiding-the-popup-this-type-of-file-may-harm-your-com)

This link helped the most for my needs, so I'll add it here, however, the first link is very helpful as well so I want to leave it.
[How to control the download of files with Selenium + Python bindings in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654358/how-to-control-the-download-of-files-with-selenium-python-bindings-in-chrome)